# cannot install spacy package while trying to create python 3.6 azure function

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, spacy

I had an error while trying to install **spacy package** on python 3.6 **azure function** as it needs a c++ compiling as a prerequisite for installation so I got this error:

> fatal error C1510: Cannot load language resource clui.dll.
>     error: command 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 4
>
> ---
>
> Running setup.py clean for spacy
>     Failed building wheel for spacy

I've tried to use wheel but it's not supported for this package.

Comment: Riham: I have the exact same problem. If and how were you able to solve? Did Andrew S's solution help?

Comment: The solution that was fit to me is to use Docker. So that I've installed the environment on Ubuntu and pushed image to Azure and it works fine.
I've followed the steps on this Link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that was fit to me and solved this problem is to use Docker. I've created a custom image and installed my environment on Ubuntu and pushed this image to Azure and it works fine. I've followed the steps on this Link for deploying my docker image on Azure: learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/…

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the C++ compiler that comes with Microsoft Visual Studio 15. It used to be a stand alone set of build tools one could install separately. Unfortunately, the stand alone build tools for Microsoft Visual C++ no longer exist. Instead Microsoft prefer you install their 6GB visual studio, which many old links direct to. Many of us realize that this requirement is despotic and want the stand alone installer back.

Despite Microsoft best efforts to redirect all hyperlinks to it (in blogs etc), to the new Visual Studio installed, the following location seems to host the older build tools for VS2015. However, it  is going to be between 3gb and 6gb in size: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/older-downloads/

The size does not make any sense for just the C++ build tools. However, I am told this is correct. It seems in true MS fashion it ships with a lot of extra baggage most of users / developers will not even care about (I don't want to cross compile C++ for Arm etc).